# Ambiguous Reference in ASP.Net Core API

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-webapi

I created a ASP.Net Core application within Visual Studio 2017 and referenced my Core library as a project reference which is now giving me ambiguous reference errors. For some reason it is getting 2 instances of each class

[image]

Here is a list of my included dependencies

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried restarting your Visual Studio? this seems to help sometimes.

Comment: Must have been my first action! Thank you

Comment: Other things to try, `DevEnv /ResetSettings`, Clean and Build Solution, Delete and re-Reference, delete all files in C:\Users\USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_db2a872f folder

Comment: in my case, I had to remove and re-install both AWSSDK.S3 and AWSSDK.Core